# Изменение формы курсора в зависимости от режима

Tags: vim, терминал

Установил `CentOS 7` на свой ноутбук, но появилась проблема. Дело в том, что мне тяжело отличить режим вставки от обычного режима, так как форма курсора одинаковая.

## Обычный режим

[image: обычный режим]

## Вставка

[image: вставка]

Можно ли это как-то исправить?

Comment: во вставке что-бы курсор был в виде |

Comment: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Change_cursor_shape_in_different_modes . Ещё, как вариант, gvim.

Comment: @Fat-Zer ответ в ответы

Comment: @0xdb ИМХО одна ссылка — не ответ, а писать полноценный мне ни интереса, ни уверенности в том, что нет более правильного ответа не хватает... не имею ничего против того, чтобы кто-то написал полноценный ответ по мотивам этой ссылки...

Comment: @Duoxx а Windows 10 здесь причём? Какой терминал?

Comment: Ни причем......

Answer (score 1):

Зависит от типа терминала. Для *xterm* и многих других, будет работать, если включить в *.vimrc*:

```
 let &t_SI = "\e[6 q"
 let &t_EI = "\e[2 q"
```

Замените символ после `\e[` для выбора типа курсора:

```
 0  -> blinking block.
 1  -> blinking block (default).
 2  -> steady block.
 3  -> blinking underline.
 4  -> steady underline.
 5  -> blinking bar (xterm).
 6  -> steady bar (xterm).
```

Comment: Проверил в mintty и PuTTY, работает.